# Setting backgroundView of Tableview

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

My problem is the layer hierarchy of "tableView.backgroundView".

I wanted to implement a background image for my tableview and all works fine in a demo project.

```
var testImage = UIImage(named: "Test_Image")
imageView.image = testImage
mytableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
mytableView.backgroundView = imageView
```

If i call this in the demo project (e.g. in the tableView Controller's viewDidLoad method) all works fine and the hierarchy is correct. All the buttons/labels/images... of the cell are loaded dynamically and they are all above the tableview's backgroundColor and backgroundView.

I even looked it up with the UI View Hierarchy Manager in Debug modus and checked it.

But in my real project, when the tableview did load, the backgroundView of the tableview is on the top of all views?

**So how can it be that the tableview.backgroundView is on the top stack of the views? All the buttons/labels/images... of the cells are between the tableview itself and the tableview.backgroundView?**

The question is actually a general one. I'm just wondering why the backgroundView of tableView can be in front of other views? Interestingly the tableview.backgroundcolor stays in the back.

If you need more information please tell me. I will try to give as much information as possible.

[image: View hierarchy]

```
@IBOutlet var mytableView: UITableView!

var man = UIImage(named: "Timeline_Background_Man")
var woman = UIImage(named: "Timeline_Background_Woman")
var imageView = UIImageView()

var delegate: CenterViewControllerDelegate?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    imageView.image = man
    mytableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
    mytableView.backgroundView = imageView
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: could you post your "real" project code to see how you add your backgroundview and other elements ?

Comment: Sure. Give me some minutes.

Comment: why don't you set the background color to your table as clear color and then add UIImageView behind your table view

Comment: I tried with clear color. But that's not a solution :) The problem is/was just the hierarchy. If you add a view to tableview it will get a special hierarchy rank. It seems so that it is pushed above the cell (in my case it was the uirefreshcontroller). And now the backgroundView of the tableview will also pushed above the uirefreshcontroller (the added subview).

Answer (score 0):

I found that Xcode can be a little buggy in terms of View hierarchy. This sometimes happens to me and to fix it I drag the background view to a new position in the hierarchy and then back to its original place. Always fixes the problem for me

Comment: I can't drag the backgroundView because it is an internal function. Like tableview.backgroundView

Comment: Oh ok, Apologies for my misunderstanding.

Comment: No Problem :) But i tried moving and deleting the the tableview outlet. Still doesn't work.

Comment: Do you have any screenshots of the problem. Are you sure the tableview cells are being populated?

Answer (score 0):

As i have seen in your code, you are just adding the `UIImageView` to your `UITableView` backgroundView, so my suggestion in spite of adding the view to `UITableView` backgroundView why not you just set the tableViews' `backgroundColor` with `patternImage` like this

```
 mytableView.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "Test_Image"))
```

Comment: Because my color and the image are independent and different.

Answer (score 0):

I've got it.

The problem was

```
self.refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
self.refreshControl!.addTarget(self, action: "refreshTVC:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
mytableView.addSubview(refreshControl!)
```

When i add a Subview to the tableView the backgroundView of the tableview jumps also to the top of the hierarchy, even above the cells. Is this a deliberative behaviour of iOS?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this was issue only for `iPhone 4s`. All other `devices` were working great. Thanks [S. Birklin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4168954/s-birklin) on pointing the issue which was `UIRefreshControl`.

Please do this and you will be able to get refresh control as well as `backgroundView` for `tableView`.

Instead of using default refreshControl object, create new `UIRefreshControl` object as follow.

```
var _refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
```

And use this `_refreshControl` object to your `tableView` as follow.

```
tableView.addSubview(_refreshControl)
```

Once you do this, you will be able to get `refreshControl` as well as `backgroundView` too.

Hope this helps.